# Using :counter_cache and :touch in the same association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

I have a `Comment` model that `belongs_to` a `Message`.  In `comments.rb` I have the following:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :message, :counter_cache => true, :touch => true
end
```

I've done this because updating the `counter_cache` doesn't update the `updated_at` time of the `Message`, and I'd like it to for the `cache_key`.

However, when I looked in my log I noticed that this causes two separate SQL updates

```
Message Load (4.3ms)  SELECT * FROM `messages` WHERE (`messages`.`id` = 552)
Message Update (2.2ms) UPDATE `messages` SET `comments_count` = COALESCE(`comments_count`, 0) + 1 WHERE (`id` = 552)
Message Update (2.4ms) UPDATE `messages` SET `updated_at` = '2009-08-12 18:03:55', `delta` = 1 WHERE `id` = 552
```

Is there any way this can be done with only one SQL call?

**Edit** I also noticed that it does a SELECT of the Message beforehand.  Is that also necessary?

Comment: It's still like that

Comment: Wow, really? Seven years later? That's crazy.

Answer (score 3):

It probably does two queries because it's not been optimised yet.

Why not branch and create a patch :D